# In Core Data, how to get all object of NSSet?

Tags: core-data, nspredicate, nsset, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I currently have the following Core Data Model:

Category

```
@interface Category : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *subcategory;
```

Subcategory

```
@interface SubCategory : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) Category *category;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *items;
```

Items

```
@interface Item : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) SubCategory *subCategory;
```

I want to get all items in a category, however when I write:

```
NSLog(@"Items in Category:%@", self.category.subcategory.items)
```

I get nothing.

What would be the way to fetch the information? Since I am receiving the class with a property I added in the ViewController:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) Category *category;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to use the Key-Value Coding
[Collection Operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE)
`@distinctUnionOfSets`:

```
NSSet *allItems = [self.category valueForKeyPath:@"subcategory.@distinctUnionOfSets.items"];
```

(Note that a better name for the to-many relationship "subcategory" would be
"subcategories".)

Alternatively, you can execute a fetch request on the "Item" entity with a predicate
using the inverse relationships:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"subCategory.category == %@", self.category];
```

The advantage of this method is that the intermediate "SubCategory" objects are
not loaded into memory.